# Why my BackgroundImage url process.env is not showing in my site?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to put a background image on my site connecting with my backend to define what image will appear. But in some cases isn't working.

When I try to put a background image on my page using the following code inside a  it doesn't appear.

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, #6666661a, #151515), url(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL}/${project?.thumbnailUrl})` }}>
```

with console.log(data) my thumbnails are returning, but I can't understand why they are not appearing on my page. Also, if I do:

```
<img src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL}/${project?.thumbnailUrl}`} alt={project?.name} className={styles.slideImg} />
```

They appear as well, but not the way I need them (in the background). It's my first time using StackOverflow so I don't know how to put a code here, I apologize. I'll put some images too, to you guys understand what I need (The image should be in the background when I use the first code, everything I have it's my default background-color).

my .env file =[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFCde.png)

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo please ?

Comment: Does HeaderAuth return something? This can also happen when the div is not having Height.

Answer (score 1):

To the css URL background you need to put the single quote ('') like :

```
backgroundImage: url('myImage');
```

for your code It can be:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, #6666661a, #151515), url('${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL}/${project?.thumbnailUrl}')` }}>
```